# Show a sequence is bounded (therefore has convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that this sequence is bounded (and hence, by B--W, has a convergent subsequence):

$$ a_{n} = \frac{n\cos^n(n)}{(n^2+n)^{1/2}}$$

I noticed that the numerator is less than or equal to $n$ for all $n$ as $\cos^n(n)$ is less than or equal to $1$, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Should I find an equation that is greater than $(n^2 + n)^{1/2}$ that is easier to work with as a denominator to show that a sequence *larger* than  $a_{n}$ is bounded? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** how about rewriting $$\frac{n\cos^n(n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} = \frac{n\cos^n(n)}{\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})}} = \frac{n\cos^n(n)}{n\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{n})}} $$ from here you should be able to figure out a bound $M$ on $a_n$ such that $|a_n| \leq M$

Comment: Seeing as cos^n(n) < 1, and root(1+1/n) < root(2), would I be correct in saying M = 1/root(2) ?

Comment: @JonathanWu Sounds good to me!

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n}=\frac{n\cos^n(n)}{(n^2+n)^5}\\-1\leq \cos^n(n)\leq+1\\- \frac{n}{(n^2+n)^5}\leq \frac{n\cos^n(n)}{(n^2+n)^5}\leq\frac{n}{(n^2+n)^5}\\- \frac{1}{n^4(1+n)^5}\leq \frac{n\cos^n(n)}{(n^2+n)^5}\leq\frac{1}{n^4(1+n)^5}\\$$now  $$n>0 \\\frac{1}{n^4(1+n)^5} \leq \frac{1}{32}\\$$ $$-\frac{1}{32} \leq a_{n} \leq \frac{1}{32}$$

Comment: The exponent on the denominator is $0.5$, not $5$

Comment: It was unclear, bad notation, $.5$ with the $.$ easy to miss.  I changed it to $1/2$.

Comment: ok . sorry . first time I saw it 5 .